# How to highlight selected item with multiple lists to choose from in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im working with Vue js and I have multiple lists rendered but i only want to select(highlight) one element. At the moment multiple items are highlighted with each click. Hope that makes sense. Here is my code snipets below

```
<template>
 <div>
    <div class='list-group'>
      <a v-for='(product, idx) in adslCapped' class='list-group-item'
         v-on:click='toggleActiveIndex(idx)' 
         :class="{'active': idx == activeIndex}" >
      {{product.name}}
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class='list-group'>
       <a v-for='(product, idx) in fibre' class='list-group-item'
          v-on:click='toggleActiveIndex(idx)' 
          :class="{'active': idx == activeIndex}" >
       {{product.name}} 
       </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
    data: {
      activeIndex: null
    },
    methods: {
       toggleActiveIndex: function(index){
         this.activeIndex = index
       }
    }
```

So as you can see I have two lists, but when I click on the first item of the first list, then  it highlights the first item in both lists. PLease note that these are only code snippets in relation to the issue i'm having.

Comment: I think you need to remove `active` class from one div as soon as the other is clicked class="{'active': idx == activeIndex :"inactive"} ", get the exact syntax for `vue`

Answer (score 1):

With your current app structure, if you want only one item to be highlighted among all the lists, you can add another variable which represents the active list.

Then you need to change the condition for the active class and check if the index is the active index AND if the list is the active list.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div class='list-group'>
  <a v-for='(product, idx) in adslCapped' class='list-group-item'
     v-on:click='toggleActiveIndex(adslCapped, idx)' 
     :class="{'active': idx == activeIndex && adslCapped == activeList}" >
  {{product}}
  </a>
  </div>


  <div class='list-group'>
     <a v-for='(product, idx) in fibre' class='list-group-item'
        v-on:click='toggleActiveIndex(fibre, idx)' 
        :class="{'active': idx == activeIndex && fibre == activeList}" >
     {{product}} 
     </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      activeIndex: null,
      activeList: null,
      adslCapped: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      fibre: ['1244', '125215', '02150']
    }
  },
  methods: {
   toggleActiveIndex: function(list,index){
     this.activeIndex = index;
     this.activeList = list;
   }
  },
})
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DevJulia/n5hg860s/3/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Okay but then how would i know which list is active? Because v-on:click is on the <a> tags. And the number of different lists is dynamically generated

Comment: You should add one parameter to your function "toggleActiveIndex" (you can rename it for better understanding) and update the value of the variable activeList with this parameter. I made a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DevJulia/n5hg860s/3/)

Comment: Thanks alot Julia your solution worked for me i just have to implement it accross my whole app now

Answer (score 0):

I know this is overkill for this simple case but you can abstract list into a component, store selected products separately.

Take a look at the example.

```js
var productList = Vue.component('product-list', {
  props: {
    value: Object,
    products: Array
  },
  template: `
<div class="product-list"><a class="ist-group-item" :class="{'active': product.id === value?.id}" @click="selectProduct(product)" :key="product.id" v-for="product in products">{{product.name}}</a></div>`,
  methods: {
    selectProduct(product) {
      this.$emit('input', product)
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selected1: null,
      selected2: null,
      products: Array(5).fill(0).map((pr, id) => ({
        id: id + 1,
        name: `Product ${id + 1}`
      }))
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    //console.log(this.products)
  },
  methods: {}
});
```

```css
.product-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ist-group-item {
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.ist-group-item:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.ist-group-item.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <product-list v-model="selected1" :products="products">
  </product-list>
  <product-list v-model="selected2" :products="products">
  </product-list>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that activeIndex is only one variable - which can't be reused for setting the index in the both lists.

The issue is that - you should be able to separate which list you want to activate when clicking within the `v-for` loop.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list1: [{
        name: "Learn JavaScript",
        done: false
      },
      {
        name: "Learn Vue",
        done: false
      },
      {
        name: "Play around in JSFiddle",
        done: true
      },
    ],
    list2: [{
        name: "Learn JavaScript",
        done: false
      },
      {
        name: "Learn Vue",
        done: false
      },
      {
        name: "Play around in JSFiddle",
        done: true
      },
    ],
    active1Index: null,
    active2Index: null
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive: function(list, index) {
      if (list === "list1") {
        this.active1Index = index
      } else {
        this.active2Index = index
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class='list-group'>
    <a v-for='(product, idx) in list1' class='list-group-item' v-on:click='toggleActive("list1", idx)' :class="{'active': idx == active1Index}">
      {{product.name}}
      </a>
  </div>


  <div class='list-group'>
    <a v-for='(product, idx) in list2' class='list-group-item' v-on:click='toggleActive("list2", idx)' :class="{'active': idx == active2Index}">
       {{product.name}} 
       </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who answered you guys on stackoverflow are the best. Julia's solution is the one that worked for me.

I have to implement it throughout my whole app and lists now.

Thanks Julia